# Python scrapy select element with display:none

Tags: css, парсер, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

Не могу спарсить элемент с значением style="display: none;"
css/xpath selector возвращает пустой список.

страница для парсинга https://www.rlsnet.ru/tn_index_id_35.htm
элемент xpath:

```html
.//*[@id='preplist_aurora']
```

css:

```html
.drug__composition.drug__list-filterresult--packname
```

Цель - достать весь текст.

Answer (score 0):

Возвращает пустой список, потому что div изначально пуст [image: Пустой див]

Данные в нем появляются только после нажатия на "+".
Не знаю, как имитировать нажатия в scrapy, но я бы лучше поискал в сторону того, как формируется запрос, который отправляется при нажатии на плюс. [image: Запрос]
В нем как раз-таки и находятся нужные данные